# Delay on write of small files to USB key

Tags: usb, usb-flash-drive

I store my files on a USB key so I can access them across computers / operating systems.  I find that often, when I'm editing a small file and then save it, there's a long delay / hang while it saves (sometimes several seconds).  I don't notice these sorts of delays when opening files, and I can copy many files to / from the disk without such long delays.  It only seems to happen when saving a file that I'm editing (e.g. in a text editor).

I use mostly Linux, but found that it happens in both Windows and Linux, and with 2 different USB keys, one formatted as VFAT and one formatted as NTFS.

Does anyone have any idea what causes this and whether there's a way to avoid it?

EDIT: I found an older 1GB USB key for which the problem doesn't happen.  I also found that the problem doesn't seem to happen on another slower computer, only this one.   It's a desktop computer with an AMD Phenom(tm) II X4 955 Processor. The motherboard is a M5A78L-M/USB3.  I've noticed the problem with more than one USB port on the computer.

Comment: Operating system and hardware specs? Have you been able to reproduce the problem on a different computer?

Comment: Hmm, good question - I tried it on an old Netbook I have which is much slower, and I can't reproduce the problem there.  So it does seem to be only this computer which has the problem.  It's a desktop computer with an AMD Phenom(tm) II X4 955 Processor.  The motherboard is a M5A78L-M/USB3.  I've noticed the problem with more than one USB port on the computer.

Comment: Can you try out another flashdrive if the speeds are still similar, could be the age of your flashdrive or your devices.

Comment: Hmm, I just tried it with an older USB key and the problem doesn't seem to happen with it.  The older one is a 1GB key which I believe only supports USB 1.  The 2 keys for which the problem did occur are 32GB (the newest) and 16GB (a bit old).

I forgot to mention the operating systems are Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10.